# create divider between radio buttons in radio group added programmatically?

Tags: android, radio-group

i have created radio buttons added to radio group programmatically, the radio group in xml is as below

```
<RadioGroup
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/rgFeedbacks"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/appbar_padding"
android:divider="@color/radiogroup_divider"
```

> 

and the radio buttons are added like below

```
 for(int i=0; i<array.size(); i++){
        rb[i]  = new RadioButton(this);
        rb[i].setId(i);
        rb[i].setText(Array.get(i));
   }
```

the problem is the divider is not showing between the radio buttons, how to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **showDividers** like this:

```
android:divider="@color/radiogroup_divider"
android:showDividers="middle"
```